# Laravel use multiple classes with nested use

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have multiple DAO classes (or Repository classes in Laravel jargon).

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;
class CompanyRepository extends RepositoryFactory
{
    public function getCompany($id)
    {
        $q = "SELECT COMPANY FROM `COMPANIES` WHERE ID > :id1";
        $result = DB::select($q, ["id1" => $id]);
        return  $result;
    }
}
?>

<?php
namespace App\Repository;
class ArticleRepository extends RepositoryFactory
{
    public function createArticle($title, $summary)
    {
      ….
    }
}
?>
```

Now I would like for one class to include once all my Repositories (30-40 Repositories) with a class such as RepositoryInclude

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use App\Repository\CompanyRepository;
use ….

class RepositoryInclude
{

}
?>
```

so that from my Controller I could simply:

```
use App\Repository\RepositoryInclude;

class MYController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct(CompanyRepository $companyRepository)
   {
       $this->companyRepository  = $companyRepository;
   }

   public function index()
   {
       $companyNameList = $this->companyRepository->getCompany();
   }
}
```

How can I do that? apparently nesting classes with a hierarchy of "use" doesn't work as if I nest a series of "include_once".

PS: I would like to use common PHP language techniques which I can reuse in the future and no Laravel "hacks", expecially if they involve command line commands which I'm avoiding as much as possible.

Comment: Are you familiar with current auto loader approaches?  see: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/  Not sure I fully follow your question but think reading up on that PSR is a good idea.

Comment: I updated my question with a missing requirement: I would like to avoid specific Laravel techniques and use some OOP or general PHP technique to solve this problem, so that in the future I can reasonably hope to be able to port to future Laravel versions or other platforms...

Comment: What about __autoload() approach?

Comment: is it really too much work to add another `use App\Repository\TypeRepository;` for each instance reference in your controller? this smells like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/321521).

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I'm rewriting a project full of $MyClassDAO = MysqlDAOFactory::singleton()->getMyClassDAO(); interspersed all around the project, I thought Laravel could at least do me this favour to begin with.